How to configure U-turn connection of ASAM opendrive 1.4 XODR(xml) file format
I am trying to make a XODR file in ASAM Opendrive version 1.4.
The problem is making a u-turn (only lane/road).
A junction should be made between the same direction of connected road.
But I can't find a good example how to configure it in XML file.
I've asked ChatGPT and other AI chats but gives only poor answers to it.


